# Node.js: Download file from s3 and unzip it to a string

Tags: node.js, zlib, aws-lambda

I am writing an AWS Lambda function which needs to download files from AWS S3, unzips the file and returns the content in the form of a string.

I am trying this

```
function getObject(key){
  var params = {
    Bucket: "my-bucket",
    Key: key
  }
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(zlib.unzipSync(data.Body))
    })
  })
}
```

But getting the error

```
Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:363:17)
    at Unzip.Zlib._processChunk (zlib.js:524:30)
    at zlibBufferSync (zlib.js:239:17)
```

The data looks like this

```
{ AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 'Wed, 16 Mar 2016 04:47:10 GMT',
  ContentLength: '318',
  ETag: '"c3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"',
  ContentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 08 08 00 f0 ad 6f 48 95 05 00 50 84 00 00 00 b4 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 30 30 33 32 35 2d 39 31 38 30 34 2d 37 34 33 30 39 2d 41 41 ... > 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Body` buffer contains zip-compressed data (this is identified by the first few bytes), which is not just plain zlib.

You will need to use some zip module to parse the data and extract the files within. One such library is [`yauzl`](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#frombufferbuffer-options-callback) which has a `fromBuffer()` method that you can pass your buffer to and get the file entries.

Comment: not sure I understood your answer. If I pass `data.Body` in `yauzl.fromBuffer`, I get a `ZipFile` object in the callback. How do I use that ? I cannot pass it to `zlib.unzipSync` since it expects Buffer.

Comment: The readme for the module describes [`ZipFile`](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#class-zipfile). It also contains an [example](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#usage).

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to be working fine with the file I am trying to access. I get an error at `zipFile.on("entry")`. `Error: unexpected EOF
`

Comment: Did you verify that the data is valid by writing the buffer to disk and trying to open it with some archive viewer?

Comment: If I download the file manually from S3, I can unzip the file and view the contents correctly. I'll just try with downloading the file programmatically

Comment: If I write the `data.Body` to a file using fs.writeFileSync, I am able to unzip the contents and view them properly

Comment: Try other zip modules then, there are plenty on npm, such as [`adm-zip`](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip), [`unzip`](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip), [`jszip`](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip), etc.

Comment: AdmZip worked! Thanks a lot! You've been a great help in understanding the process.