# Unable to create .tar.gz file from binary buffer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, gzip, tar

I am trying to simply read a .tar.gz file from a source (Salesforce) and save it to disk. I am using the [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) library in Node (5.6.0) to connect to Salesforce. When I retrieve a .txt file and save it -- it works fine with no problems.

```
conn.requestGet('/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/XXXX/VersionData', {}, function(err, data) {
  var bitmap = new Buffer(data, 'binary');
  fs.writeFileSync('new_file.txt', bitmap, {
    encoding: 'binary'
  });
});
```

But I am having problems when using trying to save the file as .tar.gz. If I use the same fs.writeFileSync -- then the file will save but it's not in the right format and I can't open it. In the below code I am using the [tar.gz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar.gz) and streamifier to convert my Buffer to a Stream but it doesn't work. I have also tried stream-buffers but I get the same problem.

```
conn.requestGet('/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/XXXX/VersionData', {}, function(err, data) {
  var bitmap = new Buffer(data, 'binary');
  var read = streamifier.createReadStream(bitmap);
  var write = targz().createWriteStream('new_file.tar.gz');
  read.pipe(write);
});
```

The error I get is:

```
events.js:154
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^ 
Error: incorrect header check
at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:363:17)
```

My problem seems similar to [Node.js: Download file from s3 and unzip it to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082921/node-js-download-file-from-s3-and-unzip-it-to-a-string) but since I am using .tar.gz files, then the suggestions there don't seem to help.

Comment: You're going to need to use an archiving library like `archiver` to work with tar files.

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your case is that you want a string or a buffer to be compressed and written to a zip file, while the variable 'read' is actually a normal buffer stream, not a compressed one.

Similarly, the problem with the tar.gz module and the targz() function is that it neither provides a mechanism to write normal data into a compressed stream, nor provides clarity in the documentation. I spent some time reading the documentation and realized that it is designed to work with files and folders only, not with in-memory data.

If you use the zlib module from the node foundation, your problem can be resolved easily, and cleanly.

```
#cat t.js
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var str = 'hello compressed world!';
zlib.gzip(str, function(err, buffer) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  fs.writeFile('./foo.gz', buffer, function(err, b) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
});
});
#node t.js
#file foo.gz
foo.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix
#gunzip foo.gz
foo already exists -- do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? y
#cat foo
hello compressed world!#
```

Hope this helps your case.

Comment: Thanks for the info here -- this helps a little bit, but my real problem is that I have this binary data already coming in from my HTTP request and calling zlib.gzip on it doesn't make sense because it's already gzipped. I also tried zlib.inflate/unzip and then trying to write the result of that to a file but I get similar errors: { [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }